# AWS S3: How do I set the TTL for an entire bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am using Cloudfront and S3 together.  I want to set the TTL to 0 for S3 files.  I know that this can be done by setting the `Cache-Control` field to `max-age=0`.

The issue is that I only know how to do this for individual files using the AWS Console.

**How do I make it so that an entire bucket will default to a TTL of 0, including files that are uploaded in the future?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set whole buckets to certain TTL using the [S3 Browser tool](http://s3browser.com/automatically-apply-http-headers.php) , the link is also a guide to setting bucket wide TTL.

Comment: I develop on a Mac.  Do you know of any Mac solutions?

Comment: The S3 Browser for Mac did not work, but I busted out my POS Windows machine, and S3 Browser Tool did the job.

Comment: Haha, maybe see if http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/17376/wine you can run the App using Wine for Mac?

Comment: So... I may have accepted this a bit too soon.  I was able to set the TTL for all existing files.  However, new files that I upload do not have the Cache-Control header set, even though I set the a Default HTTP Header for Cache-Control to "max-age=0" (and left the Bucket and File Name blank so it affects all files).  Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: Did you select the folder rather than the items in it when you went to tools and set the default http headers?

Comment: I just tried that, and it didn't fix it.  It doesn't seem that it would matter anyways though, as the Default HTTP Headers look global to my account.  (But it looks like you can then choose certain buckets and file names to apply them to.)

Answer (score 2):

Using [Bucket Explorer](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/) You can set object metadata on existing objects on that bucket as well as on objects to be uploaded in that bucket together using Bucket Default.
It available for **Mac**, **Linux** and **Windows** Os.

[image: Add MetaData for all the objects of a bucket as well as for objects to be uploaded.]

Disclosure: I am one of the developer of Bucket Explorer

Comment: To clarify, if a header is set using Bucket Default, will that mean that the header will be set when a file is uploaded to S3 from my custom server (or any other source from that matter)?

Comment: The above method will set header on all the existing objects and set bucket default for that bucket together. for more datails : http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--how-to-update-metadata-in-batch.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same TTL for the whole S3 bucket served via Cloudfront, including newly added files, then you can set this in Cloudfront.

Go to Cloudfront in the AWS console, click on Behaviours, click the distribution from this bucket, and click edit. Click "Customize" so you can set your own headers, then set min/max/default TTL as you require. In your case you want a TTL 0, so you can set the default TTL to 0. In case you want to override any TTLs that have been set on individual files you could set the max TTL to 0 too.